# How to customize FacesMessages created by bean validation annotations?

Tags: jsf-2, message, bean-validation

Is there an easy way to customize `FacesMessages` that are created by bean validation annotations?

In my case I'm using:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@NotNull (message = "Date is required!")
private Date date;
```

The message is being added to the facescontext correctly, but my message is both summary and detail at the same time, so it's displayed twice. How can I avoid that behavior?

**Edit: Solution found**

I found a solution as follows:

I'm using `p:growl` to display my facesMessages. Using the `showSummary` tag allows to hide the summary text.
For sure, the tag supports EL, so it is asking a bean for the boolean value. The job is done by method

```
public boolean isShowSummary(){
   return ! facesContext.isValidationFailed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution as follows:

I'm using `p:growl` to display my facesMessages. Using the `showSummary` tag allows to hide the summary text.
For sure, the tag supports EL, so it is asking a bean for the boolean value. The job is done by method

```
public boolean isShowSummary(){
   return ! facesContext.isValidationFailed();
}
```

Comment: Technically, this is not a solution, but a workaround. The faces messages still contains the summary duplicated as detail. This workaround just makes sure that it is simply not been displayed (but it is still there).

Comment: You're right. Solutions are still welcome, but the workaround works well for me ATM ;-)